# The best way to wind copper wire around rod for lowest resistance

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, ohms-law, copper

So I have wound 200m copper wire around a rod which gives me 180 Ω, previously I got only ~80 Ω. Both of them were randomly shuffled and the first attempt was on bigger in diameter rod. How to make magnetic fields do not interfere with each other as least as possible?

If you need any more data just say so. I will edit.

Wire Lenght 200m.
Current type: AC.

Comment: Resistance should just depend on wire type, diameter and length: Nothing else.  As for magnetic fields we need more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The only exception to what @WarrenHill said is for AC resistance.  Then you have skin and proximity effects and the way you wind the coil can impact the AC resistance.  If you're measuring at DC you should get the same results if you use the same wire with the same length no matter how you wind it.

Comment: You also have temperature, which would have no impact here.  Either way, there is no way same length of wire has 180Ω and 80Ω.  If the length is the same, those two wires would have to be 3+ sizes in AWG.

Comment: How do you "randomly shuffle" copper wire?

Comment: If you mean 'scramble wound' or 'jumble wound' it'd make little difference unless the tension you were applying were to significantly stretch the wire.  Are you sure there were no turn-to-turn shorts in the lower value coil? If you know the length or weight of the wire used, and ts diameter, you can calculate what the resistance should be.

Comment: @JYelton I don't really know how to day it in english, what I've meant is that I sometimes wind in the middle of the rod, then after some time in the ends. It's not order or consistent. It doesn't go from one point to another and then back.

Comment: @LadasnoVaidas wound messily or not wound neatly